# Export animated image view into gif or movie on Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

Folks, is there a some way to export/save animated image view to a file (either gif or some movie file type would work)?

I have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tree"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"

    android:src="@drawable/animated_tree" />
```

And animated_tree looks like:

```
<target
    android:animation="@animator/pulse_top"
    android:name="top" />

<target
    android:animation="@animator/pulse_right"
    android:name="right" />

<target
    android:animation="@animator/pulse_left"
    android:name="left" />

<target
    android:animation="@animator/pulse_bottom"
    android:name="bottom" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export to gif was done by applying this class: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm and adding callbacks to Animator object onAnimationStart/onAnimationEnd/onAnimationUpdate